# Java 7: a file containing paths to other files

Tags: java, file, path, java-7

is there any simple way (in Java 7) to:

1. open in reading mode a file containing, for every line, a path to another file
2. for every line/path, open the respective file and print the content

(Every file is a plain text file)

?

Sorry if the question is silly.

Thank you

Comment: Yes. Open the file, then use a loop and a scanner to read each line. For each line, (try to) open a new file with that path, loop and print every line..then continue to the next file.Too easy :)

Comment: There are many solutions to that problem.  What have you tried so far, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: That is a straight-forward problem, you should be able do solve that at your own

Comment: `Files.readAllLines` might be a start to read all lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read multiple lines from console and store it in array list in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621302/read-multiple-lines-from-console-and-store-it-in-array-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // open stream to path list file
    InputStream indexSource = new FileInputStream("index.txt");

    // create reader to read content
    try(BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(indexSource))) {
        // loop
        while (true) {
            // read line
            String line = stream.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // stream reached end, escape the loop
                break;
            }
            // use `line`
            printFile(line);
        }
    }
}

static void printFile(String path) throws IOException {
    // open stream to text file
    InputStream textSource = new FileInputStream(path);

    // print file path
    System.out.println("### " + path + " ###");
    // create reader to read content
    try(BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textSource))) {
        // loop
        while (true) {
            // read line
            String line = stream.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // stream reached end, escape the loop
                break;
            }
            // print current line
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    // nicer formatting
    System.out.println();
}
```